# Google chrome not rendering page correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, rendering

Here is the link
http://demo.elxer.com/new_eco/

the header (Menu and logo section of page is not recunstructing correctly on scroll) in google chrome...
Its working fine with other browser and some google chrome version I am currently using Google chrome version Version 25.0.1364.152 m, Please Help. It might be some css issue or it might be jquery or browser rendering issue, I have tried a lot to search it but could no find any answer.

Comment: I can't see a problem. Can you show a screenshot please of expected appearance and another of the problem please.

Comment: The only slight difference I can see between Chrome and Firefox is that chrome sets a slightly different weight for the font of your menu causing a slight shift on :hover - is this the issue you are trying to describe?

Comment: Chrome shows parts of the menu when scrolling. One of the nice things with modern webdesign. ;-)

Comment: It works fine in Chrome 25.0.1364.160 (mac)

Comment: Looks like a bug with chrome. +1 for research.

Comment: Cool work. Your site is looking good.

Answer (score 4):

There is not much you could do about, I'm afraid. The only thing that helped me out sometimes is forcing 3D mode with

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

I tried to set this to your div under the `#overlay`:

```
<div style="position: relative; top: 0px; min-width: 1150px; max-width: 1280px; height: 4245px; overflow: hidden; margin:0 auto; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);">
```

That worked for me, but brings another issue with the width. Maybe this is easier to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me alas thanks, just add  `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to `div#overlay`. Actually `div#overlay` was the culprit but alas it don't have to do with any section of header. I made it to check by google team.

**Check this working link** http://demo.elxer.com/eco_new/

Sorry for using your code and copying it. neighbour :)